# Is there a function in R that will let me create a new data frame that contains the duplicated values from the first data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, subset, intersect

This is my example. From this data frame I want to create a new data frame that contains the rows that based on matches in column, mgb and column, tsg thereby omitting the other rows.

```
mbr  mbg tsr tsg
1   1   g1   3  g4
2   2   g2   4  g3
3   3   g3   5  g2
4   4   g4   6  g1
5   5   g5   7  g5
6  NA <NA>   1  g6
7  NA <NA>   2  g7
```

So ideally it would return this data frame:

```
mbr  mbg tsr tsg
1   1   g1   3  g4
2   2   g2   4  g3
3   3   g3   5  g2
4   4   g4   6  g1
5   5   g5   7  g5
```

So far I've tried:

1) `intersect(df$mbg,df$tsg)` but that only returns a lists of the matches between the columns e.g. g1, g2 etc...

2) `df2<-[intersect(df$mbg,df$tsg),]`

which returns this:

```
     mbr  mbg tsr  tsg
NA    NA <NA>  NA <NA>
NA.1  NA <NA>  NA <NA>
NA.2  NA <NA>  NA <NA>
NA.3  NA <NA>  NA <NA>
NA.4  NA <NA>  NA <NA>
```

I'm very new to R and trying to teach myself so any advice would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your description. It looks like all you're doing is filtering for rows where mbg and tsr are non-NA. Are you trying to find rows where mbg is contained within tsg, and it's just coincidence that that's also just all the non-NA rows? If so, you should be able to use `%in%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting what you're looking for correctly, you appear to be on the right track, just running into issues with syntax.  Try this

```r
df2<-df[df$mbg %in% intersect(df$mbg,df$tsg),]
```

`intersect(df$mbg, df$tsg)` was returning the values that occur in both of those columns.  Adding df before the brackets identifies the data frame you want a subset of, which you were missing before, and the `df$mbg %in%` part says that you want the rows where the value of mbg is included included in the intersection.

Comment: Thank you! sorry for the late reply but this solution worked great!

Comment: Hey, the function worked for 1 set of data very well but when I used a bigger set of data with my disparity between columns it didn't really work at all, please can you help me out?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "disparity between columns" and how it "didn't really work at all"--like how didn't it work?  I did see someone else point out above that you really don't need the intersect part and can just do `df[df$mbg %in% df$tsg, ]`.  (I had left the intersect just to build off of what you'd already tried.)  Maybe removing the intersect part would help if it's a performance issue?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the `intersect` piece.

```
df2 <- df1[df1$mbg %in% df1$tsg, ]
```

The `%in%` operator will return a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` as to whether each element in `mbg` is found (or intersects) with values in `tsg`

Alternatively, using the `dplyr` library (which if you are new to R, I would recommend learning)

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- filter(df1, mbg %in% tsg)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thanks for your help, I tried this and another solution below and both worked well. I'm currently looking through the dplyr package now. So I'm trying to use the dplyr way and my columns seem to fall out of matching very quickly, i.e. after the first 4 results, why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

If you would simply like to remove NA's and write to a new dataframe:

```
complete.df <- na.omit(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  semi_join(df, c('mbg' = 'tsg'))

#   mbr mbg tsr tsg
# 1   1  g1   3  g4
# 2   2  g2   4  g3
# 3   3  g3   5  g2
# 4   4  g4   6  g1
# 5   5  g5   7  g5
```